# Does DSR or L3DSR allow for a secret back channel between hosts? How can it be stopped?

Tags: network, tcp, threat-mitigation, backdoor, covert-channel

This [Serverfault question describes how a load balancer](https://serverfault.com/q/490649/51457) can embed data that will be round-tripped back to the originating node. Traditionally DSR can't exceed the boundaries of a broadcast domain.

L3DSR allows an interaction to exceed those boundaries.

What is the potential, risk, and mitigation of using this as a covert channel for sharing data between two nodes?